# How do I get the pod to expose the prometheus monitoring port in Flink application mode on Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, apache-flink, prometheus

I'm running `flink run-application` targetting Kubernetes, using these options:

```
-Dmetrics.reporter.prom.class=org.apache.flink.metrics.prometheus.PrometheusReporter
-Dmetrics.reporter.prom.port=9249
```

I specify a container image which has the Prometheus plugin copied into `/opt/flink/plugins`. From within the job manager container I can download Prometheus metrics on port 9249. However, `kubectl describe` on the flink pod does not show that the Prometheus port is exposed. The ports line in the kubectl output is:

`Ports:         8081/TCP, 6123/TCP, 6124/TCP`

Therefore, I expect that nothing outside the container will be able to read the Prometheus metrics.

Comment: welcome to SO. Looks like the issue is when you defined the k8s yaml file of the flink pod. Can you post that? Have you trie to use `9250-9260` as it is described here (https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/deployment/metric_reporters/#prometheus). Have you tried to use `metrics.reporter.prom.host: 127.0.0.1` as well?

Answer (score 2):

You are misunderstanding the concept of **exposed ports**.
When you expose a port in kubernetes with the `ports` option (the same apply with Docker and the `EXPOSE` tag), nothing is open on this port from the outside world.

It's basically just a hint for users of that image to tell them *"Hey, you want to use this image ? Ok, you may want to have a look at this port on this container."*

So if your port does not appear when you do `kubectl describe`, then it does not mean that you can't reach that port. You can still map it with a service targetting this port.

Furthermore, if you really want to make it appear with `kubectl describe`, then you just have to add it to your kubernetes descriptor file :

```
...
  containers:
  - ports:
      - name: prom-http
        containerPort: 9249
```